Modular Properties of Torus correlation functions
While working with the partition functions of integrable system, we often encounter the following functions:
$$
S_{1/2,0}(z,\tau)=\frac{y+1}{y-1} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+yq^n)(1+y^{-1}q^n)}{(1-yq^n)(1-y^{-1}q^n)}\\
S_{1/2,1/2}(z,\tau)=\frac{1}{y^{1/2}-y^{-1/2}} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+yq^{n-1/2})(1+y^{-1}q^{n-1/2})}{(1-yq^n)(1-y^{-1}q^n)}\\
S_{0,1/2}(z,\tau)=\frac{1}{y^{1/2}-y^{-1/2}} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-yq^{n-1/2})(1-y^{-1}q^{n-1/2})}{(1-yq^n)(1-y^{-1}q^n)}
$$
where $\{1/2,0\}$ are the spin structures for Fermion models on a torus, and $y=e^{2\pi i z}$. These are formally torus correlation functions. For more about these functions and their derivation from physical point of view, I would suggest Marcus Berg. I want to study the modular properties of these functions. Under modular $T$, things are quite easy. For instance $S_{1/2,1/2}(z+1,\tau+1)=S_{0,1/2}(z,\tau)$. But under the modular $S$, I find the transformations to be bit cumbersome to find. They may mix among themselves quite non-trivially. As an exercise, I derived the transformations for string of multiplicative series ($\Theta(z,\tau)$ function, or more simply $\eta(z,\tau)$ functions), but so far have been unable to do anything for these functions. Help is appreciated.
